# How do i use advanced search in Outlook to look for the copyright symbol.

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

I've been able to search for special characters that are on the keyboard, like @, but I can't find a way using advanced search to enter the character for copyright.  In Outlook itself, one can use (c), or alt+cont+c, or unicode 00A9, but the search box in advanced search doesn't accept the last two, and apparently doesn't interpret the first one as the copyright symbol.

Ultimately, I'd like to search for all messages that contain the word copyright alone, but exclude messages that contain the word copyright followed by the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Go in Windows to *Programs » Accessories » System Tools » Character Map.*

[image]

[Here](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/6-ways-to-access-character-map-in-windows-10.html) you can find how to open it in Windows 10.

Select and copy the character that you want. In this case `©`.

Paste in the search box of *Outlook*.